# jquery datatable doesn't work with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I use JQuery DataTable. I created a function, send data to datatable from  spring Controller at ajax succes .till now everything is good,now i want to add a date range filter,it works with the default content of the table but the problem is that when the content of the table changes with the ajax function the date range filter still filtring on the default content.

this is the date range filter

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
        var min = $('#date_added').datepicker("getDate");
        var max = $('#date_modified').datepicker("getDate");

        var d = data[2].split("/");
        var startDate = new Date(d[0]+ "/" +  d[1] +"/" + d[2]);            


        if (min == null && max == null) { return true; }
        if (min == null && startDate <= max) { return true;}
        if(max == null && startDate >= min) {return true;}
        if (startDate <= max && startDate >= min) { return true; }
        return false;
    }
    );


        $("#date_added").datepicker({ onSelect: function () { table.draw(); }, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
        $("#date_modified").datepicker({ onSelect: function () { table.draw(); }, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
        var table = $('#datatable').DataTable();

        // Event listener to the two range filtering inputs to redraw on input
        $('#date_added, #date_modified').change(function () {
             var table = $('#datatable').DataTable();
            table.draw();
        });


    });
```

this is the ajax function

```
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    contentType : "application/json",
    url : "http://localhost:8081/BackEndFinalVersion/listCourriersArrivés",
    data: { get_param: 'value' },
    dataType : 'json',
    timeout : 100000,
    success :function(data) { 
        trHTML = '';
        $('input[type=radio][name=radioInline]').change(function() {

            if (data == null) {
                  alert("No records"+data);
                   //trHTML = '<tr><td>'No Records to be show'</td></tr>';
                } else if(this.value == 'option2'){
                  $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                        $("body").on("click", "#datatable tr", function () {

                            window.location ="/Pro/mail_detail?id="+item.idCourrier;    
                            });

                    trHTML += '<tr><td>' + item.expéditeur + '</td><td>' + item.société + '</td><td>' + item.date + '</td><td>' + item.objet + '</td></tr>';


                  });
                  $('#datatable tbody tr').remove();

                  $('#datatable tbody').append(trHTML);
                }

            trHTML = '';
    }) 
    },      



    error : function(e) {
        console.log("ERROR: ", e);
        alert(e);
    },

});

});
```

Comment: Have you tried reinitiating datatables after inserting the new data?

Comment: i have tried to add  `table.ajax.reload();` after the  `$.each` but it doesn't work

Comment: tell me how to  reinitiate datatables if you have another idea